# get frames per second of an 3rd party app using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python: I was wondering if it is possible to get the fps of an application, then print it with python, I don't own or know any of the app's code, so inserting code to count frames inside the actual game wouldn't work, nor would screen capturing the app, and I want the app's framerate, NOT the system's.

Not quite sure where to start. Tried screen recording then counting the frames from that, but that has a significant delay, and also tends to be inaccurate to what steam tells me the fps of the game is.

Comment: Could you not get a screen recording software, that will tell you the fps of a particular window?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Point is, this is firstly a yes/no question and secondly there is way too little info about what the context is to tell how to do this (which I guess is your actual question).